# Problems with Boolean search mode in mysql FULLTEXT INDEX

Tags: mysql, numbers, boolean

I have a problem with the Boolean search method in MySql. I am not getting out of this.
I have 3 columns, set as VARCHAR, where I have in two columns only words and in the third column also numbers. I use the plus operator so that any given search word must be contained in the returning row.
But, when it comes to the numbers, I always get an empty result.
The query below returns an empty set, even if the number 2 is contained in the col3!
What is the problem?

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('+apache +httpd +2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Here is a piece of sample data. But I understand now why it is not returning anything. Thank you for this.

The format below exportet from SQL Database ist JSON, **{"colum_name":"colum_data"}**

```
{"reverse_dns":"net-2-32-38-169.cust.vodafonedsl.it","protocol":"tcp","port":"443","state":"open","service":"http","product":"Microsoft IIS httpd","version":"10.0","extrainfo":"","cpe":"cpe:\/a:microsoft:iis:10.0","scantime":"1591110220","timestamp":"2020-07-16 17:41:32","id":"200150","tunnel":"ssl","ip_address":"2.323.81.69","hostname":""}
```

Comment: You need to include 1 letter "words", as the (innodb) default setting only indexes words that have at least 3 letters, so "2" is currently not in your index. See e.g. [innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1 performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60143351) (and read and follow the answer carefully: you need to change the setting, restart the server, then rebuild the fulltext index).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this was one of the problems. So I face another one. I have in col3 a number like 235.5.8.9. With dots. If I delete the dots, it finds the row and returns it correct. But not with dots. How can I solve this?

Comment: A fulltext search does not know a word with dots. It knows words, and assumes that dots are not part of a word, but split 2 words. Can you share some sample data? You may be "misusing" the fulltext search: a fulltext search is originally intended to search for words in long(er) (english) texts that cannot reasonably be split into distinct columns, and gets less effective/more problematic the more you deviate from that; if e.g. "235.5.8.9" is a build number and the only information in your column 3, fulltext search might not be the right tool and there could be better ways to search for that.

Comment: @Solarflare thank you for your help. I updated my question, maybe you know a workaround?